# ExtJS: Adding spinner to combobox

Tags: extjs

I need/would like to add a spinner (up and down arrows) to an Ext JS (6.6.0) Ext.form.field.ComboBox. Something like this:[image]

The requirement is to keep the combobox functionality but also add the possibility to step through the list step by step.

I have to admit that I am quite new to Ext JS. I did some research and went through the Ext JS documentation a bit but I still have no clear idea how to best implement this.

Can anybody suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to your problems would be to add [triggers](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-triggers).

This is the same technique that the combobox is using to apply a "trigger" (button) to the field.

[Triggers](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-triggers) have a handler config in which you can access (on user click) the combobox. From there you can easily access the current value and the [store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html) to get all the information you need to set the "next" or "last" value in relation to the values [store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html) position.

Here is a working live example: [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3m7i)

Here is a code example:

```
    // The data store containing the list of states
    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data: [{
            "abbr": "AL",
            "name": "Alabama"
        }, {
            "abbr": "AK",
            "name": "Alaska"
        }, {
            "abbr": "AZ",
            "name": "Arizona"
        }]
    });

    // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
    Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        store: states,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        triggers: {
            spinner: {
                type: 'spinner',

                upHandler: function () {
                    const me = this,
                        position = me.getValue() ? me.getStore().indexOf(me.findRecordByValue(me.getValue())) - 1 : -1;

                    if (position >= 0) {
                        let newValue = me.getStore().getAt(position).get(me.valueField);
                        if (newValue) {
                            me.setValue(newValue);
                        }
                    }
                },

                downHandler: function () {
                    const me = this,
                        position = me.getValue() ? me.getStore().indexOf(me.findRecordByValue(me.getValue())) + 1 : 0;

                    if (position < me.getStore().getRange().length) {
                        let newValue = me.getStore().getAt(position).get(me.valueField);
                        if (newValue) {
                            me.setValue(newValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot for your immediate and extensive reply.

I have 1 more question: Is it possible to display the arrows not side-by-side but one above the other? To make it look more like the original spinner compoment? I played around a bit with the stylesheet classes (e.g. using 'x-form-spinner-up' instead of 'fa-arrow-up') but they are still desplayed one next to the other.

Comment: Hello! I just modified my code example and the fiddle. There is actually a "spinner" trigger I didn't know about, (here is the documentation: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.trigger.Spinner.html)